# How Can I Have an App in the App Launcher Open in New Window or Tab

Tags: jquery, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, applauncher

I am using SharePoint 2016 On-Prem and would like the Tiles in the App Launcher to Open in a New Window or Tab.  Is there a possible jQuery option to have the Apps in the App Launcher Open in a new window?
Bismarck

Answer (score 0):

*In SharePoint Server 2016, users can quickly and easily get to all of their SharePoint and Office 365 workloads directly from the app launcher. Now in addition to those, you can also add your own custom tiles that point to other SharePoint sites, external sites, legacy apps, and more. This makes it easy to find the relevant sites, apps, and resources to do your job.*

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/custom-tiles-in-sharepoint-server-2016

Comment: That does not answer my question.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea ?  Is there a jQuery Option ?